# how to determine the subclass type in a factory pattern other than using if else and switch?

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I wanted to try the factory pattern and was able to implement it, but when
 generating for more than a few classes, i thought this will be ugly!! so any clarity or suggestions would be really appreciated...

My Superclass:

```
public abstract class Output {

    public abstract void generate(Data dat); }
```

i got my other classes extending from Output like

```
public class generateXML extends Output{
.
.
.
}
```

My question is related to here:

```
public class generatorFactory(){

public Output generate(String str){
```

// or getting an Object as an argument like (Object obj)

```
if(str.equals("xml"){  
return new generateXML();  
}  
else if.........  
......  
}
```

Is there any way we can determine the subclass type avoiding checking for each type??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use newInstance() to instanciate a generator whose classname you've built from the parameter:

```
public Generator getGenerator (final String type)
{
    final Class generatorClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("Generator"+type);
    final Generator generator = (Generator) (generatorClass.newInstance());
     return generator;
}
```

PS: I highly rate you to follow the rules of Java: if generateXML is a class, it should be written GenerateXML.

More over: take care by naming your classes. (1) An Object generateXML shouln'd extend Output, because it isnt' an output. (2) "GenerateXML" is a verb, i.e. an action. It is therefore not a correct word to name an object, but a method. You could name the object per example "XMLGenerator".

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I am little confused on your 2nd tip ""GenerateXML" is a verb, i.e. an action. It is therefore not a correct word to name an object, but a method. You could name the object per example "XMLGenerator" " do you mean the  class name?

Comment: Yes I do. The best is in my opinion.

Comment: Yes I do. You should name your class `XMLGenerator`, instanciate it by `final Generator myGenerator = new XMLGenerator()` and use this instance with `myGenerator.generate()`.    In your particular case, however,  you will have `Generator myGenerator = (Generator) (generatorClass.newInstance());`

Answer (score 2):

You should consider replacing your if-else chain with a map.

Rather than having to write the code that checks for all the strings you want to support you just have a copule of lines to retrieve the element from the map.

You will, of course, need some more configuration code to put the items in the map, but that should be trivial.

[Here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/transform-switches-maps) it is a nice post about this topic (in PHP)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum` which can be passed to factory and return factory object based on enum passed. The only thing is you can not export it as API.

```
 enum Type
{
    XML {
        @Override
        public Object getFactory() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };

    public abstract Object getFactory();
}
```

If you have to expose it like API then you can do something like below.

```
interface IType {
    public abstract Object getTypeFactory();
}

enum Type implements IType {
    XML {
        @Override
        public Object getTypeFactory() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

And change Factory method implemetation to

```
public static Object getFactoryByType(String name) {
    Type type = Type.valueOf(name);
    return type.getTypeFactory();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection.

```
Object generated = getClass().getMethod("generate" + type.toUpperCase()).invoke(this);

public Object generateXML();
public Object generateJSON();
public Object generateCSV();
```

Comment: thanks for your fantastic suggestion, reason being I got to learn reflection!!(never heard of it before :) )

Comment: A feature of this appraoch is that you can add methods without having to write addiitonal "wiring" code.

Comment: this one is good in addition to sun's, just in case anyone is intrested... [http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

Comment: yes i am just getting to understanding it,it is quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to call `new` everytime I'm not sure you can bypass the branching process. Someone has to know what to give you back.

If it was for singletons you could initialize an HashMap `"xml"=>generateXML singleton`

After second though, you may modify your String attribute for  differents `Type` classes MyTypeXML, MyTypeJSON, ...
and then use method with the same name but different type.

```
public Output generate(MyTypeXML xml) { // This will go for XML }
public Output generate(MyTypeJSON json) { // This will go for JSON }
```

But for factories, I'm not really against the if...else coding.